# GIF And Video Not load for iCloud photos Using PHAsset

Tags: swift, phasset, phimagemanager

i am working with loading **images, videos and gif** from local album(**photos app**) using **PHAsset**.

All asset working fine and load successfully when iCloud "**Download and Keep Originals**" Option enable.

I am facing issue when **photo need to be downloaded from iCloud**, with iCloud "**Optimise iPhone Storage**" Option enabled.

I already do a lot of search and refer many code but not finding solution.

**Some Reference Code which i used.**

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
options.version = .original
options.isSynchronous = false
options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

 options.progressHandler = {  (progress, error, stop, info) in
            print("progress: \(progress)")
 }

 if let assetID = self.mediaData.assetID {

           let obj = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [assetID], options: nil).firstObject

            if let asset = obj {

                PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: options) { (data, strInfo, orinted, value) in
                    if let da = data {
                        if let img = UIImage.init(data: da) {
                            print(strInfo)
                            print(orinted)
                            self.imageView.setGifImage(img)
                        }

                    }
                }

  //                    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: view.frame.size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: {
  //                        (image, info) in
  //                        
 //                        if let img = image {
 //                            self.imageView.setGifImage(img)
//                        }
//                        
//                    })

            }

        }
```

Any one know proper solution for this Please share.
**Thank In Advance.**